# Mean curvature of graph over its tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, tangent-spaces

Let $S$ be a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $p\in S$ a point on the surface.
By the implicit function theorem $S$ can be locally written as a graph of a function, e.g. $V\cap S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x,y)\in U, z=f(x,y)\}$ for some open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$, open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and some smooth function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$
By choosing local coordinates we can identify $U$ as part of the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$, furthermore we can set $f^{-1}(p)=(0,0)$. In this case, the mean curvature at $p$ is given by $H=\frac{f_{xx}\;\;+f_{yy}}{2}$ (average of second derivatives at $p$) and principal curvatures are $f_{xx},f_{yy}$.

Is this correct? If it is, how can one describe this more precisely than "choosing local coordinates..."? If it is not, how could I achieve a similar result (surface as graph over its tangent plane and easy formula of $H$)?

Thank you.

Comment: It's true at the origin only.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct. The mean curvature can be defined as half of the trace of the shape operator (minus the differential of the unit normal vector). **If the surface is the graph of a function**, the normal vector field at the point $(x,y,z)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\nabla(z-f(x,y))}{|\nabla (z-f(x,y))|} &= \frac{\nabla z- \nabla f(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}} \\ &= \frac{e_3- \nabla f(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}\, ,
\end{align*}
with $\nabla=(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z)$. Note that, $\nabla f=(\partial_x f,\partial_y f,0)$.

The trace of the differential of this unit normal vector field is nothing but the divergence of it. Therefore
\begin{align*}
2H&=-\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{e_3- \nabla f(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}\right)\\ &=\frac{\Delta f}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}+(\nabla f(x,y)-e_3)\cdot \nabla\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}\right) \, .
\end{align*}
Now, **if the graph parameterization is with respect to the tangent space at** $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$ then $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=0$ and, therefore, $H$ reduces to
$$2H(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\Delta f(x_0,y_0) \, .
$$
This is the formula you were writing and, in general, it is true at every point of $(x,y,f(x,y))\in S$ where $\nabla f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: You had better distinguish between something true at one point and something true in general. And why did a $z$ show up in $f(x,y)$ all of a sudden?

Comment: I edited it. I was keeping in mind that $f$ is though as a function of $x,y,z$ in the computation, although $0$-homogeneous along $z$.

Comment: But you missed my main complaint. This holds *only* at a particular point, not for general $(x,y,z)$. Your notation needs to make this fixed point explicit from the outset.

Comment: But I wrote it. It holds at the points $(x,y,z)\in S$ where the gradient of $f$ vanishes. I don't see the point. I never stated that it holds for general points. I stated that it holds at $(x,y,z)\in S$ if the parameterization is with respect to the tangent space at $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: This is very misleading, but OK. It looks like you're writing a general equation, and the casual reader will think so.

Comment: I see your point. But if you want, please edit it. So that when someone in the future will read this will not get confused.

Comment: @idefix 11:  Two examples. 1) Surfaces of revolution at their equators 2) Catenoid  isometrically deformed to a helioid.

Comment: @TedShifrin, just a remark. The nabla that you replaced with just two variables, must be of three variables. Because we are looking at the surface as the zero level set of the function $F(x,y,z)=z-f(x,y)$. And therefore one has to treat $z$ as an independent variable. That's why $\nabla z$ gives you $e3$.

Comment: Yes, that one place. Everywhere else it's just two variables. So introduce $\tilde\nabla$ the three places it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

> By choosing local coordinates we can identify $U$ as part of the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$, furthermore we can set $f^{-1}(p)=(0,0)$.
> In this case, the mean curvature at $p$ is given by $H=\frac{f_{xx}+f_{yy}}{2}$ (average of second derivatives at $p$) and principal curvatures are $f_{xx},f_{yy}$.
> Is this correct?

I think it is not always true that the principal curvatures are $f_{xx},f_{yy}$.

We need to rotate the xy-plane such that the x-axis and y-axis along the directions of the two principal vectors.

(But $H=\frac{f_{xx}+f_{yy}}{2}$ is always true, since Laplacian is invariant under orthogonal transformations)